# Losing all data of my Byte array in asp.net mvc during model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on attaching files to a message system that I am building, we are using a Kendo browser to get the file and its upload methods. I am running into a problem in that when I successfully upload a file to be sent as an attachment model, and pass it back to the service that sends the message I am losing the Data property of the model that holds the byte array and the mime type.

1. page is bound to a wide body view model with a message model, and an attachment model
2. view model is passed to mvc controllers send method which takes a message model and an optional attachment model
3. The attachment model has two properties, the mime type and the Data property which is of type byte[]
4. The secure message model has a property on it that is a list of attachments, it is of type IList

Here is my controller action that does the kendo-Uploader magic

```
 public ActionResult SaveDocumentFile(HttpPostedFileBase DocumentFile)
    {
            AttachmentModel attachmentModel = new AttachmentModel();
        attachmentModel.DocumentFile = new DocumentFileModel();
        attachmentModel.DocumentFile.Data = FileManager.GetFileData(DocumentFile);
        attachmentModel.DocumentFile.MimeType = DocumentFile.ContentType;
        attachmentModel.FileName = DocumentFile.FileName;
        return Json(attachmentModel);
    }
```

This takes the results of the file pick and sends it back to the client as an attachment model, which gets stuffed into the View Model.

Here is my Contoller action that sends my message

```
        public ActionResult SendMessage(SecureMessageViewModel messageView)
    {
        if (messageView == null)
            messageView = new SecureMessageViewModel();
        if (messageView.SecureMessage == null)
            messageView.SecureMessage = new SecureMessageModel();
        if(messageView.Attachment == null)
            messageView.Attachment = new AttachmentModel();
        if (messageView.Attachment.DocumentFile == null)
            messageView.Attachment.DocumentFile = new DocumentFileModel();

        IList<AttachmentModel> attachmentList = new List<AttachmentModel>();
        attachmentList.Add(messageView.Attachment);
        return Json(staffMessagingService.SendMessage(messageView.SecureMessage, attachmentList), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This passes a secure message model and an attachment model to the service layer which is where it crashed because the service layer checks for Data(a property on Attachment model) and throws an exception if there is no data, which in this case there is none, even though it was present from the html->Angular->to the HTTP stream. Then it goes off into the void.

When I break in the save method on the client I see my view model with the attachment model in it loaded with the mime type and the byte array. 
  When I break in the controller on send Message view has an attachment with a mime type but no Data. 
  I put a watch on Request in the debugger and can see the array in the http stream but some how my model is not binding to it.

Has anybody ever had a similar issue? And if so what was the problem, so far dr Google has been of no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling this is not the best solution but I did find a work around, I added a string property to my attachment model and converted the byte array to a string before sending it back to the client. I then convert it back to the array in the send method before I push it up to the server. This gets me past the fact that my array is not being bound to my model.
the method I used to convert was the HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode and encode methods.